# why the size of a parameter is unknown?

Tags: rust

Here is my code:

```
use std::mem::{size_of, transmute};

#[derive(Debug)]
#[repr(C)]
struct Header { // some file header
    magic:      u32,
    data1_len:  u32,
    data2_len:  u32,
}
fn main() {

    let buffer: Vec<u8> = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]; // whatever 

    let header: Header = {
        unsafe { transmute(buffer[0..(size_of::<Header>())]) }
    };
}
```

but when compiling I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[u8]` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> main.rs:15:22
    |
15  |         unsafe { transmute(buffer[0..(size_of::<Header>())]) }
    |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

Actually my type is sized, I am telling the precise range of bytes that my type occupies. Why does the compiler complain? It should derive the size of my type by itself.
How do I tell the compiler that my size for transmute is the size of the the `Header` struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being `Sized` is a property of the type, not of any particular value. `[u8]`, and `[T]` in general is unsized. You can fallibly try to convert to a sized type, however.

```
let data: [u8; size_of::<Header>()] = buffer[0..size_of::<Header>()].try_into().unwrap();
```

`try_into` usually returns a result, but since we know the size is correct, we can simply `unwrap` it. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3558b4c85a53daac9644f0791e931f5d)

```
// The trait `TryInto` isn't in the prelude,
// so we have to import it to use its methods.
use std::convert::TryInto;
use std::mem::{size_of, transmute};

#[derive(Debug)]
#[repr(C)]
struct Header {
    // some file header
    magic: u32,
    data1_len: u32,
    data2_len: u32,
}
fn main() {
    let buffer: Vec<u8> = vec![
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0,
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0,
    ]; // whatever

    let header: Header = {
        let data: [u8; size_of::<Header>()] = buffer[0..size_of::<Header>()].try_into().unwrap();
        unsafe { transmute(data) }
    };
}
```

**Note:** this step only works because `[T; N]` implements `Copy` if `T` implements `Copy`. We're copying the data out of the vector. If this isn't what you want, you'll need to remove the data from the vector using `Vec::splice` or similar. They can't both own that data.

You might also consider just getting a reference to a `Header`, which should actually work here without copying anything or modifying the vector. I'd avoid the wild unsafety of `transmute` and use the (slightly less unsafe) casting of raw pointers.

Unfortunately, the obvious thing to do here doesn't work since the alignment of a `Header` is 4 bytes, but the alignment of `[u8]` is only one byte. Pointer casting from `&[u8]` to `&Header` may cause an alignment fault. The reason that wasn't a problem with `[u8; _]` to `Header` was that `transmute` takes the array by value and returns a properly aligned value. See [pull request #38670](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/38670).

One way around this is to make `Header` `repr(C, packed)`, which forces its alignment to be to one byte. This might make things a little slower in general (but remember: benchmark first!). I'm fairly certain this causes more problems than it's worth due to unsoundness around references to `packed` structs, so be careful with this. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=468671a2051251842d134d0dccaa0da7)

```
use std::mem::size_of;

// We can't derive anything unless we also derive Copy
// one of the downsides of this approach
#[repr(C, packed)]
struct Header {
    // some file header
    magic: u32,
    data1_len: u32,
    data2_len: u32,
}
fn main() {
    let buffer: Vec<u8> = vec![
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0,
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0,
    ]; // whatever

    let header: &Header = unsafe { &*(buffer[0..size_of::<Header>()].as_ptr() as *const Header) };
}
```

Comment: Great stuff! The pointer solution is the one I will go. But can I just align the buffer to 8 bytes? I tried ``#[repr(align="8")]`  but it says it works only on structs or enums...
the `Vec` also doesn't support alignment. So looks like the only way to go is to allocate memory with std::alloc:alloc() and use a size which is going to be multiples of 4 , or better 8 bytes.